# Select dataset columns after GroupBy

Tags: dataset, associations, filtering

Very basic question. Probably showing my ignorance, but if I have a dataset like the example in the docs

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

and I want to group by column "b" I type

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"]]
```

I get the beautiful result

[image]

But if I just want columns "a" and "c", how do I get them? Naively I type

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"], {"a", "c"}]
```

but that crashes and burns
[image]

What's going on? How do I select what columns I want after GroupBy?

Comment: Note you get a nested dataset after you `GroupBy["b"]`

Comment: So GroupBy doesn't "descend"?

Comment: ``Dataset`AscendingQ`` and ``Dataset`DescendingQ`` can tell you it is or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
dataset[GroupBy[Key["b"] -> KeyDrop["b"]]]
```

or

```
dataset[GroupBy[Key["b"] -> KeyTake[{"a", "c"}]]]
```

or

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"], KeyTake[{"a", "c"}]]
```

or

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"], All, {"a", "c"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's only half what I'm trying to understand. What specifically is wrong with dataset[GroupBy["b"], {"a", "c"}]? Why is the "All" needed? How would I have known that? What did the error message try to tell me?

Comment: @ChrisNadovich I try to stay away from explaining to much when it comes to datasets. I failed to grasp details and there are people around who didn't fail while I'm just using them intuitively :) You can hold on with an accept to not discourage those folks from answering.

Comment: Intuition never seems to work for me with these Mathematica Dataset things. I do just fine with SQL intuition, when using SQL, but it leads me to madness here.  Anyway, I think I found the answer I was looking for. Group by is considered "descending" (you can look it up!) but it, in fact, does not descend. It's a kind of a non-operator. So that's why the "All" is needed: because All would have been needed to descend past the rows  without the GroupBy, so it's still needed.

Answer (score 6):

This answer ([19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152006/19542)) is incorrect in stating that `GroupBy` is not a descending operator. Evaluate the following:

```
ClearAll[f]; 
dataset[GroupBy["b"] /* f]
```

> ```
> f[<|"x" -> {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>, 
>             <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>}, 
>   "y" -> {<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>, 
>           <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>}, 
>   "z" -> {<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>, 
>           <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}
>  |>]
> ```

When you `GroupBy` you add another level to the `Association` hierarchy. The first level (where `f` is above) contains the keys of the grouping.

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"], f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second level (where `f` is above) contains all the records that have been grouped. This is a list of `Associations`. You must indicate which of these `Association`s in the list you want to access. In this case all are wanted so `All` is specified.

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"], All, f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`f` is now at the level where the `Association`s can be accessed. Here you can enter the keys of the items you wish to return.

```
dataset[GroupBy["b"], All, {"a", "b"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As can be seen from the steps above, `GroupBy` does act while descending. The issue the OP has (hopefully now: had) is not understanding the affect of effecting `GroupBy`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Practical answers are given by @Kuba, but the real answer I was looking for is this.

Even though `GroupBy` is considered "descending" (you can look it up!), it, in fact, does not descend. It's a kind of a non-operator. So that's why selecting the columns doesn't work in my question.

First I need to start at the top level and move past the rows. So the `All` is needed: because `All` would have been needed to descend past the rows without the `GroupBy`, so it's still needed.